# Python: if string starts with a string from a list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, apt

I'm reading a file and each line has a tag, followed by a colon and then the information that I want.  A sample file would look like

```
Package: com.something.something
Section: Utilities
Name: Something
```

etc, (It's an apt packages index if you're wondering)
so I want to loop through each line and see if that line starts with an element from a list.  I was thinking something like

```
PkgInfo={}
Tags=['Package', 'Section', 'Name']
for line in reader.readlines()
    if line.startswith(element in Tags):
        PkgInfo[element]=line.split(': ')[1]
```

This code doesn't work, but hopefully you understand what I am trying to do.  How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: no need to apology, happened to everyone! just correct it and the comment becomes superfluous! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution with slightly different logic:

```
PkgInfo={}
Tags=['Package', 'Section', 'Name']


for line in reader.readlines():
    entry = line.strip().split(': ', 2)
    if len(entry) != 2:
        continue
    element, value = entry[0], entry[1]
    if element in Tags:
        PkgInfo[element] = value

print PkgInfo
```

And pay attention to the fact that iteration over elements was not only one problem. 'Package' in `Tags` was defined as 'Package: ', `Tags` in loop referenced as `tags`, `split.line` instead `line.split()`, value isn't stripped.

Comment: I find this solution particularly elegant, perhaps because it integrates best into my existing code.  :D But there are tons of other good answers here! It's just that this one works best for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you just split line at `:` and then test whether the first part is one of your keywords. This can easily be done by using a `set` and the `in` operator:

```
tags = set(['Package', 'Section', 'Name'])
pkgInfo = {k: v.strip() for k, v in (line.split(':') for line in reader) if k in tags}
```

Or the longer version:

```
tags = set(['Package', 'Section', 'Name'])
pkgInfo = {}

for line in reader:
    k, v = line.split(':')
    if k in tags:
        pkgInfo[k] = v.strip()
```

But note that this will fail if there is not exactly one colon in each line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PkgInfo = {}
Tags = ['Package', 'Section', 'Name']

for line in reader.readlines():
    for element in Tags:
        if line.startswith(element):
            PkgInfo[element] = line.split(': ')[1]
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with all solutions based on split() is that they will probably break if colon appears more than once. This is less elegant but more robust:

```
PkgInfo = {}
Tags = ['Package','Section','Name']
splitter = ': '
splitLen = len(splitter)
for line in reader.readlines():
  firstColon = line.find(splitter)
  if firstColon > 0: 
    key = line[:firstColon]
    if key in Tags:
      pkgInfo[key] = line[firstColon + splitLen:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over Tags:

```
PkgInfo={}
Tags=['Package: ', 'Section', 'Name']
for line in reader.readlines():
    for tag in Tags:
        if line.startswith(tag):
            PkgInfo[tag]=line.split(': ')[1]
            break
```

Comment: Seems not exactly what he wants. Notice when a string starts with more than one string in the given set.

Comment: Added a `break`. However, that's impossible given his example code.

Comment: Yep dude, that's true. I was just pointing that out. And it looks well now. :P

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
 PkgInfo={}
 #I assume it should be 'Package' not 'Package: '
 Tags=['Package', 'Section', 'Name']

 for line in reader.readlines()
    k, v = line.split(': ')
    if k in Tags:
        PkgInfo[k] = v
```

or even quickier and dirtier two liner:

```
 #I assume it should be 'Package' not 'Package: '
 Tags=['Package', 'Section', 'Name']

 PkgInfo = dict(line.split(': ') for line in reader.readlines() if line.split(': ')[0] in Tags)
```